# In JUnit 4, is there a way to run a piece of code before all @BeforeClass in a custom runner that extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I would like to run some methods before `@BeforeClass` is invoked in a custom runner that extends `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`.

How do I do this?

When overriding the `runChild` method, I've discovered that it runs per test method.

```
protected void runChild(FrameworkMethod child, RunNotifier notifier) {
    System.out.println("a");
    super.runChild(child, notifier);
    System.out.println("b");
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
a
test here
b
a
test here
b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you override [`ParentRunner#classBlock`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.java#L189)? BlockJUnit4ClassRunner extends ParentRunner but does not override `classBlock` (or mark it `final`), so you should still have access to override it.

```
/**
 * Constructs a {@code Statement} to run all of the tests in the test class.
 * Override to add pre-/post-processing.
 * [snip]
 */
protected Statement classBlock(final RunNotifier notifier) { /* ... */ }
```